# How to connect an Android Chat Application to Openfire server

Tags: android, chat, openfire

I am trying to connect an Android chat app in Eclipse to my own Openfire server. The code I am using is from the Samsung developers site (http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application) and I am having difficulty in connecting the app to my server.

The problem comes from declaring the connections:

`public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";`

`public static final int PORT = 5222;`

`public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";`

`public static final String USERNAME = "userid@gmail.com";`

`public static final String PASSWORD = "password";`

This is the example provided by the site, but I am unsure of what the fields should contain if I am using my own openfire server, as opposed to the example above. If someone could give an example of what I should do to connect to my own server, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do? If you want to build and chat application, you must read about "XMPP". You should take a look at [Asmack Library](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack) which help you easily build an chat application in Android.

Comment: Hi. The problem I am having is connecting the app to my server. The app appears to work but when I run it in an emulator, it fails to connect to the server.

Comment: you should show your log!

Comment: It says "Failed to connect to Chris" (Chris is the host name) and "remote server timeout(504)"

Comment: your local host is: `talk.google.com`? I dont think so... you should put your local host address there.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry if I'm not being clear. I'm not using talk.google as my host, as I'm using my own. What I would like is to see if it is possible to connect to my own server using the above code but with changes  i.e. using my own host name but I'm not sure what I should have for the service. In this case it won't be gmail. Thanks for your responses

Comment: @Chris Allen: i m having a same problem, while connecting to "talk.google.com" it is working fine, but at time of my own server it shows " `` not-acceptable(-1) Encryption (SSL or TLS) is required to connect to this server.` but my server is not providing any security option.

Did you found any solution?

Comment: Change PORT to `143` from `5222` and it works..